# Global Variable and Prototype function

Tags: c, performance

I would like to get some advices, I know that in terms of getting the code to run it has not much of a issue, but I would like to know if perhaps placing the global variables before or after the prototyping function affect at the code performance? and in terms of keeping your code clean is it best to declare variable before prototyping functions or after?

Thank you.

Comment: This is definitely opinion territory, but a common one is going to be that the best practice with respect to global variables is to avoid them if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if perhaps placing the global variables before or after the prototyping function affect at the code performance?

No.

> keeping your code clean is it best to declare variable before prototyping functions or after

Follow your group's coding standards.